# Convert outliers and NA in a dataframe to NaN

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, data.table, nan

I have the following dataset:

```
structure(list(media = c(56.257, NA, NA, 
56.256, 56.267, NA, NA, 56.265, 56.262, 56.259, 56.265, 
56.263, 56.265, 56.262, 56.264, NaN, 56.268, 56.265, 560.26, 
5600.2, 56.265, 56.262, 56.263, 56.264, 56.263, 56.265, 56.271, 
56.271, 56.28, 56.281), cycle_rounded = structure(c(1604487600, 
1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 
1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 
1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 
1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 
1604487600, 1604487600, 1604487600, 1604489400, 1604489400), class = c("POSIXct", 
"POSIXt"), tzone = "UTC")), row.names = c(NA, -30L), class = c("data.table", 
"data.frame"), .internal.selfref = <pointer: 0x000001d9d6a21f90>)
```

I would like to 1) Get values in `media` variable, above and below the IQR (interquartile range - outliers) of all values in `media` and convert them to NaN. 2) Convert NA to NaN, because when I will plot `geom_line()` it automatically gives me a break in the line, that is what I need.

I try something like it: `mutate(media = case_when(media > 1.5*IQR(media, na.rm = T) ~ NaN))` But won't works.

Thanks for appreciate all help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IRQ` is a range, so a difference of values. I think you need to include the median as well, from which the IQR is relevant.

For this code, I generally would use the IQR for both above and below the median of the values. If you really need to remove just above it, then you can remove the `between(..)` logic and simplify it.

### data.table

```r
DT[
  with(list(med = median(media, na.rm = TRUE), iq = IQR(media, na.rm = TRUE)),
  !between(media, med - 1.5*iq, med + 1.5*iq)), media := NaN]
DT
#      media       cycle_rounded
#      <num>              <POSc>
#  1:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  2:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  3:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  4:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  5: 56.267 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  6:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  7:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  8: 56.265 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  9: 56.262 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 10: 56.259 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# ---                           
# 21: 56.265 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 22: 56.262 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 23: 56.263 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 24: 56.264 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 25: 56.263 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 26: 56.265 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 27: 56.271 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 28: 56.271 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 29:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:30:00
# 30:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:30:00
```

### dplyr

```r
DT %>%
  mutate(
    media = if_else(
      between(media,
        median(media, na.rm = TRUE) - 1.5*IQR(media, na.rm = TRUE),
        median(media, na.rm = TRUE) + 1.5*IQR(media, na.rm = TRUE)),
      media, NaN)
  )
```

Calculating the median and IQR multiple times seems a bit unnecessary, so we can preassign outside the call. However, if you're ever dealing with grouping, then that won't work, so here's an alternative:

```r
DT %>%
  mutate(
    media = with(
      list(med = median(media, na.rm = TRUE), iq = IQR(media, na.rm = TRUE)),
      if_else(between(media, med - 1.5*iq, med + 1.5*iq), media, NaN))
  )
#      media       cycle_rounded
#      <num>              <POSc>
#  1:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  2:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  3:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  4:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  5: 56.267 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  6:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  7:     NA 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  8: 56.265 2020-11-04 11:00:00
#  9: 56.262 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 10: 56.259 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# ---                           
# 21: 56.265 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 22: 56.262 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 23: 56.263 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 24: 56.264 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 25: 56.263 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 26: 56.265 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 27: 56.271 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 28: 56.271 2020-11-04 11:00:00
# 29:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:30:00
# 30:    NaN 2020-11-04 11:30:00
```

or if you prefer `case_when`:

```r
DT %>%
  mutate(
    media = with(
      list(med = median(media, na.rm = TRUE), iq = IQR(media, na.rm = TRUE)),
      case_when(between(media, med - 1.5*iq, med + 1.5*iq) ~ media, TRUE ~ NaN))
  )
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer it was very elucidating. I really appreciate that.